# Eclipse : how to link and merge two linked ressources in the same project?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, resources, buildpath

I have two projects, both have the folder "rsc" which contains all the ressource used. 
 
  what i want to do is access the ressources of the first project from the second project, i am not allowed to change any code, so i can't change the folder's name, it should stay "rsc".
how do i link the "rsc" folder of the first project to the second project, how can i tell eclipse to merger the two of them, any ideas on how should i do it?
because obviously it is impossible to add the same folder (name) twice.
and thanks in advance!
Edit:
the objective is : tell eclipse to get the ressources from the first project, then if none by that URI was found, go to the second (current) project.

[image]